# Реализация декодера по минимальному расстоянию Хемминга на языке Java

Tags: java

Подскажите , как можно реализовать алгоритм декодирования линейного блочного (n,k)-кода С на языке Java. На вход , как я понимаю , можно подавать либо проверочную, либо порождающую матрицу кода в произвольном виде и вектор V длинны N. Далее надо привести матрицу к систематическому виду , построить вторую матрицу, вычислить параметры (n,k,d)-кода, сформировать таблицу информационных и кодовых слов, затем декодировать вектор V, вычислив расстояние Хемминга между вектором V и каждым информационным словом. Данную задачу нужно решить для случая кодов, заданных над кольцом вычетов, т. к. кодов над Fq, где q-простое число.

Comment: Пробовали ли вы самостоятельно решить эту задачу, что у вас получилось, с какими проблемами столкнулись?